# How to create a custom alert using Redux ? (Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I want, instead of using the default `Alert.alert` method, to create my own so that I could change the background of my `Alert`, whether it's successful or not. To do so, I use a `Modal`, which put in my root component, App.js (so that the modal can appear on each screen) :

App.js

```js
// ...
const Navigation = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

// Render the app container component with the provider around it
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigation />
        <CustomAlert /> {/* <--- here */}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I do so because I don't want to place my `<CustomAlert />` component on each Screen that I use. If someone has another approach I'll take it.

CustomAlert.js

```js
// ... (imports)

class CustomAlert extends Component {
  render() {
    const { customStyle } = this.props;
    const { title, description, enabled } = this.props;
    const { reinit } = this.props; // dispatch
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          animationType="none"
          transparent
          visible={enabled}
        >

          <View style={styles.fullScreen}>
            <View style={[styles.content, customStyle]}>
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={styles.title}>
                  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{title}</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.desc}>
                  <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{`${description}`}</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.buttons}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      reinit();
                    }}
                    style={styles.button}
                  >
                    <Text>OK</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    type: state.alert.type,
    title: state.alert.title,
    description: state.alert.description,
    enabled: state.alert.enabled,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    reinit: () => dispatch(reinitState()),
  };
}

export default stylesWrapper(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomAlert));
```

I proceed like that:
In my function that shows the alert, I simply change my redux store:

helper.js

```js
// ...
export const infoAlert = (title, msg, type = 'error') => {
  store.dispatch(setTitle(title));
  store.dispatch(setDescription(msg));
  store.dispatch(setType(type));
  store.dispatch(setEnabled(true));
};
// ...
```

The behaviour is good but I have this warning :

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

I suspects this has one reason between those two:

- Using `store.dispatch` as a general function doesn't know anything about the component that called him, so this message indicates that It might *rerender* it (which is bad)
- infoAlert is called inside a functionnal component (Redux Form), and it's state shouldn't change (something like that)

Here an example of call infoAlert (at the bottom):

```js
const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  keyboardType,
  secureTextEntry,
  autoCapitalize,
  autoCorrect,
  meta: {
    touched, error, warning, active, dirty,
  },
}) => (
  <View>
    <TextInput
      style={[styles.textInput, (active) && styles.active,
        (touched) && (((error) && styles.error)
          || ((warning) && styles.warning))]}
      {...input}
      onChangeText={input.onChange}
      onBlur={input.onBlur}
      onFocus={input.onFocus}
      value={input.value}
      keyboardType={keyboardType}
      placeholder={label}
      secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
      autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
      autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
    />
    {(touched && !active && dirty) && (((error) && infoAlert('Erreur', error))
        || ((warning) && infoAlert('Attention', warning)))}
  </View>
);
```

Do someone has an idea of how to remove this Warning ?
Do someone has another way (maybe simpler) to create a custom alert (without putting the component itself everywhere) ?

Screens
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have a warning because you mutate your state directly in render function (you call `infoAlert` function in `renderField` component). Try to use `useEffect` hook to call `infoAlert`

Comment: Thanks you, I'll try to do this when useEffect will be available on Expo